# JQuery Validation on dynamic controls MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem validating dynamic addes inputs on GridView. I have partial views and each partial view has its own GridView. On my _Layout I have all links to scripts like jquery.validation.min.s etc. GridView is wrapped in a form so I have form id. Function for appending new row to GridView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.addCostObject', function () {
        var existRowSave = $('.saveCostObject').length;
        var existRowEdit = $('.updateCostObject').length;
        if (existRowSave == 0 && existRowEdit == 0) {
            $('#gridCostObject tbody').append('<tr>' +
                   '<td><a href="#" id=\'saveCostObject\' class="saveCostObject"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/save_.png")" /></a> <a href="#" id=\'cancelSaveCostObject\' class="icancelSaveCostObject"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/save_cancel.png")" /></a></td>' +
                   '<td></td>' +
                   '<td><input type="text" name=\'costObject\' id=\'costObjectName\' class=\'costObjectNameClass\' placeholder=\'Cost Object Type\' data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required"/></td>' +
                   '<td><input type="text" name=\'objectIdName\' id=\'objectId\' class=\'objectIdClass\' placeholder=\'Object ID\' data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required"/></td>' +
                   '</tr>');
        }
        else {
            alert('Save/Update or Cancel your previous record!');
        }
    })
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

At the end of my view I have a script for vaildating and appending rules:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#gridCostObject").validate("add", {
        rules: {
            costObject: {
                required: true
            },
            objectIdName: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            objectIdName: {
                digits: "Object id contains only digits"
            }
        }
    })

})
```

At the save click, debugger always says that object form does not have 'valid'. I've tried putting my script everywhere in my view and trying all possible combination so far. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#yourFormSelector')
```

should help :)
It reinitializes the validation for your form - after that, the method will be available for your newly loaded elements

Comment: Not working. Cannot read property error. and I have validate.js before unobtrusive.js in _layout.

Comment: Please mention which property is missing

Comment: What I saw on another question that I can't find now is that you also need:

$('#yourFormSelector').removeData('validator').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');